# Formatting x-axis in ggplot when axis tick labels are in Year-quarter

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
Dat = rbind(data.frame('name' = 'A', 'val' = sample(1:100, 10, replace = T), 'date' = as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 quarter', length.out = 10))),
            data.frame('name' = 'B', 'val' = sample(1:100, 10, replace = T), 'date' = as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 quarter', length.out = 10))),
            data.frame('name' = 'C', 'val' = sample(1:100, 10, replace = T), 'date' = as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 quarter', length.out = 10))))

ggplot(Dat, aes(x = date, y = val, fill = name))
```

However in the x-axis I want the tick labels should show something like `2020-Q1`, `2020-Q2` etc instead of default labelling.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Any pointer will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify `zoo::scale_x_yearqtr` format argument...

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
ggplot(Dat, aes(x = date, y = val, fill = name)) +
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%Y-Q%q")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>